# Web mapping with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping

On a pedestrian wayfinding scenario, I need to drape some extruded buildings close to the road as the user navigates along the road on a 2D Map Background. I hope I can use OpenLayers and ReadyMap for this. I have vector data in shape file format. I am a newbie to web-mapping. Any ideas on this to start with?

Comment: There should be a grey check mark next to each answer on your questions. It's where the up/down vote buttons and ranking are. Click the check mark next to the answer that worked best for you. That will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a huge amount of info to start helping you here. We need specific problems rather that general ones. Why don't you start with the [OpenLayers Examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) and take it from there. When you have a more specific problem then that is the point to start asking questions.

The OpenLayers Examples page is a really good starting point to see various things you can do with it and how, although bear in mind that some of them don't work all the time!